# Grails MongoDB Lists do not update, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I am currently using Grails 2.5.4, with the MongoDB plugin (org.grails.plugins:mongodb:6.0.0.RC1) and whenever I try to update a List of any domain class, it doesn't work, example:

Votation class:

```
class Votation {

String question
int minVotes
List <VoteOption> options
User owner
Chat chat

static belongsTo = [chat: Chat]
static embedded = ['options']

static constraints = {
    owner nullable: false
    chat nullable: false
    //question nullable: false
}
```

VoteOption class:

```
class VoteOption {
   String option
   String url
   List <User> voters

   static belongsTo = [chat: Chat]
}
```

When I try to update the list:

```
 //some more code...
 Votation votation = Votation.findById(votationId as Long)
 VoteOption option = votation.options.find { it.option == votationOption }
 User user = User.findOrCreateNew(params.user)
 if (option.voters) {
     option.voters.add(user) // THIS DOESN'T WORK!
 }
 else {
     option.voters = [user] //This DOES work
 }
```

This is just an example, I have 2 more domain classes that also have Lists, and they don't work either.
Restarting Grails does not fix this, and this also happens on the other developer's computer, so it's not my enviroment. Everything else is saved correctly

Comment: It's not `option.voters.add(user)` when using GORM it's `option.addToVoters(user)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

 //some more code...
 Votation votation = Votation.findById(votationId as Long)
 VoteOption option = votation.options.find { it.option == votationOption }
 User user = User.findOrCreateNew(params.user)
 if (user) {
     option.addToVoters(user) // <----
 }

 option.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
```

Ref: http://docs.grails.org/2.1.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/addTo.html

Comment: I just added the save() method. If the GORM is not able to save due to validation error, it will throw ValidationException error.

Comment: It doesn't throw an Exception, and .validate() returns true, that's what's most puzzling about this

Comment: you may not even need the if statement to check if voters exist. i made the modification on the code above. give that a try.